# How to make new structure from existing in matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab

I have structure `stations` with fields `name` and `code`.
For example:

```
stations = struct(...
    'name',{'a','b','c','d'},...
    'code',{[0 0],[0 1],[1 0],[1 1]})
```

(I will change this structure, add new stations-name and code etc.)
I want to make new structure `sessions'`which will also have fields `name` and `code` but values will be combination of two stations?

For example:

```
stations = struct(...
    'name',{'ab','ac','ad','bc','bd','cd'},...
    'code',{[0 0 0 1],[0 0 1 0],[0 0 1 1],[0 1 1 0],[0 1 1 1],[1 0 1 1]}).
```

I'm trying something like:

```
for i=1:numberOfStations-1
    for j=i+1:numberOfStations
        strcat(stations(i).name,stations(j).name);
        cat(2,stations(i).code,stations(j).code);
    end 
end
```

but I don't know where to put those values.

Comment: why is this tagged Android?  Why is it not tagged matlab?

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` you have is a struct array so you access each element like:

```
stations(1)

ans = 

    name: 'a'
    code: [0 0]
```

Then for a specific element and member

```
stations(2).name

ans =

b
```

If you want to add to the struct, you can do the following:

```
stations(end+1) = struct('name','hi','code',[1 1]);
```

If you want to merge an new array of structures to your current one:

```
% current struct array, stations
% new data, new_station_data
for ii=1:length(new_station_data)
    station(end+1) = new_station_data(ii);
end
```

Hope this helps!